# User adding tags that aren't relevant

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-badges

What should I do if someone is adding tags that are not relevant?

It seems like the reason is to get a gold badge to be able to close duplicates.

I deleted the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag, but it's possible the tags will be added later.

Some examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49077405/revisions), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49074599/revisions), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48841842/revisions), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48871983/revisions),
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48928947/revisions)

Similar: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49040364/revisions),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48448627/revisions),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49644482/revisions).

Comment: No biggie, just rollback edits you are not happy about.  Learning how to get along with each other is another matter, keeping the Q+A in the [python] tag relevant is everybody's job.

Comment: If a person with a gold badge in a tag adds their tag to a question, that takes away their power to dupe hammer that question, so that worry isn't actually an issue.

Comment: @DavyM but it allows them to close other questions with the tag...

Comment: @Braiam "you edit that question, you can close other questions." How is that related here?

Comment: @user202729 jezrael is claiming the motivation is "to get a gold badge to be able to close duplicates", Davy M is claiming that's not an issue, I specify how it could become an issue.

Comment: It certainly can be an issue if abused, particularly for gold badgers that hang around in chat with other gold badgers. but if it's abused, we have a flag system and moderators to deal with it. no biggie.

Comment: Would you mind accepting PM 2Ring's answer instead, it may serve as a canonical answer for the version based tagging issue.

Comment: Just roll it back, and when the same user does the same mistaken tagging multiple times, drop them a comment note on the question, explaining why it's mistaken. Simple huh. (And I've never seen an abuse case, must be v rare)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Every Python question ought to have the generic [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag. It is unfortunate that many new users post Python questions with only the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag, or some other version specific tag, without including the generic tag. Not only does it make dupe-hammering harder for those of us who only have the generic Python gold badge, it makes it harder for those questions to be searched. Also, there are plenty of people who follow the Python tag page and who will simply not see questions that don't have the generic tag.

So adding the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag to questions where it isn't needed, just to help one get the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) gold badge, is misguided. The effort should instead go into adding the generic tag to the questions that don't have it. Of course, plenty of the Python questions that are missing the generic tag don't *really* need to be tagged correctly because the question is of such low quality that it is fated for closure / deletion anyway.

---

But how does one decide when the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag (or some other version-specific tag) *is* needed? At this point in time, we should consider Python 3 to be the default, not Python 2 (which will reach its official End of Life sometime in 2020). A generic Python question should be treated as a Python 3 question, unless there's good reason to believe otherwise. IMHO, a version-specific tag is only required if it is required in order to correctly interpret the question or to provide an answer that will work correctly for the OP.

There are some major differences between Python 2 and 3. The fact that the Python 2 `print` statement doesn't exist in Python 3 is *not* a major difference, since the `print` function can be enabled in Python 2.6+ via the `__future__` import. Similar remarks apply to the change in the `/` division operator. Sure, you can simply wrap parentheses around the parameters to a Python 2 print statement, (IOW, parenthesize the sole operand of the print statement) but that's not a great idea since if that is changed to have multiple operands, the output will be that of a tuple, and therefore different to what a proper print function call would output. Sometimes answerers assume that a question must be Python 3 simply because they see what look like `print` function calls, this can be a dangerous assumption!

A related issue is that the evil old `input` function (which evaluates user input) has been killed in Python 3, and the old `raw_input` function has been renamed `input`. This does cause a degree of confusion to many new programmers, and has been the source of many questions. When answering such questions the symptoms are generally fairly obvious, but it's helpful if we don't have to guess which version the OP is using.

But there are several important cases where version tagging is *vital*. The main one, IME, is on Unicode questions, since there are major differences in how Unicode is handled in Python 2 vs Python 3. Sometimes you can tell from the symptoms of the OP's problem which version you're using, but sometimes they don't give us enough information to determine that, and we shouldn't have to waste our time doing that detective work. Closely related is how Python 2 doesn't distinguish well between text and bytes, whereas Python 3 makes a clear distinction.

The other main difference is that many functions / methods in Python 2 that return lists instead return some kind of iterator in Python 3. Once again, we can often guess from the symptoms, but once again, it would make life easier if we didn't have to guess, or wait for the OP to respond to comments enquiring about the version they're using.

Also, there's an important difference in how class definitions are written. In Python 2, `class A:` creates an old-style class, you need to inherit from `object`, i.e., write `class A(object):` to get a new-style-class. In Python 3, there are no old-style classes, so in Python 3 `class A:` and `class A(object):` both create a new-style class. In many situations this isn't a big deal, but it can cause problems in Python 2 if someone doesn't realise that old-style classes exist and they have various deficiencies that new-style classes overcome.

There are a few other differences that arise from time to time, eg the standard `csv` module in Python 2 expects files to be opened in binary mode whereas Python 3 insists that they be opened in text mode. And of course there are various features in Python 3 that simply don't exist in Python 2 (at least, not in the standard library), so Python 3 code using those features won't be helpful for someone stuck on Python 2, but generally such OPs do add a Python 2 tag to their question.

It's often possible to write generic code that will give the same results on Python 2 and Python 3. However, in many situations such code is *not* optimal: it means you can't use powerful new Python 3 features that don't exist in Python 2, or the code does extra unnecessary work on Python 2. Eg if a call returns an iterator in Python 3 but a list in Python 2, and you need an actual list, then you can wrap the call in `list()`. The output will be the same in both versions, but obviously it's wasteful in Python 2 to create that redundant new list, and it can have a noticeable impact on performance if that code occurs in an inner loop. In such cases, if the question is tagged as Python 2 it's probably a Good Idea to briefly mention these facts in your answer.

---

There are many popular old Python questions that were written in the days when Python 2 was the main Python version. In many cases, their answers are still quite good, but in many other cases they sorely need updating in order to be relevant to Python 3. This can be a problem when such questions are used as dupe targets. Sure, new answers can be added to such questions, but such new answers can be hard to see if the old answers have very high scores. IMHO, it makes sense to add a Python 2 tag to such questions if they don't have it already. But I guess the topic of modernizing the existing base of Python questions and answers is a topic for another Meta question.

Jon Clements has a great list of specific Python 2 vs Python 3 issues in his answer to [When answering to Python questions should we assume that the op is running a recent version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176029/when-answering-to-python-questions-should-we-assume-that-the-op-is-running-a-rec). Of course, the environment has changed somewhat in the intervening 5 years. Python 3 has had some important improvements, almost all popular 3rd-party libraries now offer Python 3 support, and many of those now do not support versions earlier than 2.7, if they support Python 2 at all. And most importantly, the Python user base has significantly migrated away from Python 2 to Python 3. OTOH, it's still not unusual to see questions from new Python students who are starting out on Python 2. Of course, learning Python 2 now as a precursor to learning Python 3 makes about as much sense as learning Shakespearean English as a precursor to learning modern English. :)

Answer (score -6):

So I feel compelled to answer this post. As others rightly point out, *the system is open to abuse*.

But what we must consider is correct / incorrect tagging, *not* correct / incorrect intentions.

Yes, my intention *was* to increase my `[python-3.x]` score so I have the ability to close duplicates, like I can in `[python]`. However, I intended to do this *only when I believed a question to be relevant to* `[python-3.x]`.

The intention may be widely viewed as dishonest. But the outcome may be correct. As it happens, *some* of those posts may have no noticeable relevance to version, and they have been rolled back. As I have already commented, I will be more careful in future.

The problem with moderating *based on intentions* is multifold:

- You may be doing the community a disfavor. Good outcomes *can* come from *bad* intentions.
- Intentions may be bluffed. I *could* claim I was editing tags for some other reason.
- Whether an intention is *good* or *bad* is not always clear cut.

What you *can* moderate on is outcomes:

- Are posts tagged *incorrectly* [previous answer + comments suggest even this is not clear cut]?
- Is the community likely to be misled?
- Has this caused any *harm* or *abuse*?

If I find posts that I believe *should* be tagged `[python-3.x]`, I will tag them. If other users think I am tagging them incorrectly, they can roll back. If someone believes I am doing SO a disservice, they can flag an example and moderators will take appropriate action.

In short, I think there are sufficient controls in place for these situations.

Comment: There's some info in [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367118/4014959) that you may wish to read.

Comment: @PM2Ring, Thanks for that. I'm fed up of every single request of mine being (pretty much) marked as a dup of some archaic post or plain ignored. I've asked for uniting expertise across version-tags, requiring non-version specific tags, improving how-to-tag instructions. Well, the effect is, I will happily continue tagging `[python-3.x]` *where I feel it's appropriate*. It's not entitlement culture here, it's the effect of how summarily my requests are dismissed. Of course I'm wrong. But admitting this won't change what I do. Sad, isn't it?

Comment: Certainly tag with `[python-3.x]` when appropriate, but _definitely_ tag with `[python]` if a Python question doesn't have the generic tag (and the question isn't destined for oblivion).

Comment: You will get [python-3.x] badge by answering [python-3.x] tagged questions. No need to rush it, or falsely inflate it, you will get there soon anyway.  *Adding* [python-3.x] when there is not version-specific reason (i.e. code is python-2 *incompatible*) does a disservice to the community.

Comment: @wim, That's not really true. [Because of this problem.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365548/improve-how-to-tag-instructions)

Comment: Sorry, which part is not really true?  I don't see how the question you linked is relevant.

Comment: @wim, Just because someone says "this is what `[python-3.x]` is for" doesn't make it so. The question I link to demonstrates this fact. I think I misunderstood you, apologies. I thought you were saying I will get the badge when I answer genuine `[python-3.x]` questions.

Comment: By all means add it if it's relevant.  In the original post I see many cases where it was added, but it was not relevant. Anyway, there are plenty enough [python-3.x] questions around to get the gold badge without needing to edit tags at all.