# How to handle persistent bullying

Tags: discussion, moderation

A couple of my meta posts have been sidetracked by a user who **persistently attributes every question to a fight between myself and another user**.

What then happens, because this user has a huge following, everyone jumps on the bandwagon and **gets sidetracked from the question I am asking**. To the extent that my question stops being addressed on its merits alone.

Here are some of the comments (they don't read better in context, either):

**Exhibit 1**

> [...] Is there any chance for this nonsense to stop or does it take having
>   one of you give up and not come back?

**Exhibit 2**

> [...] There is something going on between you and another hi-rep [python]
>   contributor, having that spill over into meta like this is not
>   productive. Learn to live with each other, be tolerant.

Flagging doesn't work, they are persistently declined.

I am on good terms with the other user. Like we all do, we may disagree on specific issues.

**How can I ask a question without it being manipulated into a perceived war with another user?**

Comment: It's not against you. He does that to everyone. Just don't engage.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, My problem is as soon as he comments, *my original question becomes irrelevant*. That's a problem.

Comment: I've been there as well. Almost tempted to answer "I have exactly the same problem, do you have a solution ?" but that would be flagged :) the guy is one of the reasons I'm not posting so many meta questions lately (that and the downvotes :))

Comment: Did you flag exhibit two as "No Longer Needed"? Or did you flag and explain to a mod that it had nothing to do with the question? Or did you not bother flagging that one? (I found that one, and really... It had nothing to do with the question you asked. So if you flagged it and it was declined... It'd be worthwhile to know _why_ it was declined, because that sounds like a correct flag in my opinion...)

Comment: @Kendra, I flagged Exhibit 2 as Rude & Abusive [contravenes Be Nice: assume good intentions] and separately as "in need of moderator intervention" - both declined.

Comment: Your first exhibit, however, is _mostly_ relevant to the question at hand- You asked a question, the user in question pointed out something they saw as incorrect in your statements... Whether or not _they_ were correct doesn't matter, the comment does at least (mostly) address your question. The part you quote could have been done without, but it doesn't necessarily _need_ to be removed.

Comment: Exhibit 2 is most definitely _not_ rude and abusive. What did you explain with it in your "In need of mod" flag? Not constructive/no longer needed I would argue, but there's nothing "Rude and abusive" in either of your quotes (or the original comments)

Comment: @Kendra, My problem is the deliberate disruptiveness. The user *persistently avoids the question*, attributing a hidden agenda. That does not **assume good intentions** as part of the "Be Nice" policy.

Comment: I can agree that the question was 100% avoided in the second exhibit, but in the first their comment does at least partially address your question and something they see as needing clarification/correction. (The correct purpose of comments, after all.)

Comment: Just tell who it is? Hans?, if that is the case you need to find an equilibrium between listening and just ignoring. He is part of the meta feature (mods tend to decline on meta).

Comment: @Kendra The first comment doesn't seem to fall in line with "[Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)". In my opinion it is rude, belittling, and very unwelcoming.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic. This guy has a huge following. What he says is gospel. Every witty comment of his gets upvoted half a dozen times, or a dozen. As soon as people read it, my question becomes irrelevant and descends into nothing. It's starting to feel personal. The mods are on his side.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I guess I don't understand why high rep users should get a pass? I would think high reputation users would be held to a higher standard than average users. It seems a little disheartening to see the opposite.

Comment: @jpp ask your questions on meta.stackexchange.com for a change. I'm moving there, most of questions asked on meta SO can be asked on meta SE.

Comment: Er... I'm not a fan of the user you are complaining about **at all**. Definitely not a _follower_. And I still find the "exhibit A" very relevant to the question, even if harsher than I would like. And neither comment is _rude or abusive_.

Comment: @yivi It seems many of the posts I see on SO meta are about not being welcoming to new users. If I had a comment like the first one left on a question of mine by someone with such a high status, I would delete my account and not come back.

Comment: @jpp You've got your causality reversed.  People aren't supporting Hans because of who he is and because they adore him personally, but rather Hans simply understands the sentiment that many of the active users here feel.  Your assertion that he's following you personally seems...unlikely, at the very least.  He, and many others, are simply active users on meta, and regularly follow most questions posted in general, not *just yours*.

Comment: @Servy, If that's true, he should **address the question**, not me. As soon as he attributes a hidden agenda, **that hidden agenda is perceived as gospel**.

Comment: @jpp I don't see how he isn't.  Again, you're just *assuming, without basis*, that everyone who is agreeing with him is doing so because he has a lot of rep, and not because they *actually agree with him* (or because he has a good understanding of what many of the users here feel).  Yes, it's a lot easier to just dismiss someone's arguments by saying that everyone who agrees with them must being doing so because they just like him; it's a lot harder to consider the possibility that all of those people actually feel the same way.  But it's more productive for you to assume the latter.

Comment: _"Perceived as gospel"_? So if anyone agrees with this user, they must have been manipulated, right?

Comment: @yivi, Given *none* of you know the conversation I've had with my "archenemy" - absolutely, yes.

Comment: @Servy lets be honest you and Hans are tough on meta, it's not easy when you start. Some of us learn to live with you others feel you are very intimidating. It's true you have tons of knowledge, but this meta shows a problem of how you share this knowledge with new users..

Comment: @jpp: as I said, I feel your pain: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364099/abusing-tag-edits, in that case, it ended not so badly, though

Comment: An issue I'm finding with Exhibit 2, by the way: You claim your questions get derailed after these comments, but I see no other comments on that question that aren't discussing what you're asking. In other words, neither of your exhibits, to me, really show what you're trying to tell us is going on. =/ Do you have other examples? (And yes, context does matter in these cases, given part of your claim is that these comments then derail the entire rest of the comments away from your question. Please, save us the trouble and link us the context?)

Comment: @Kendra, count the upvotes (don't worry, you won't find it hard, there aren't many comments upvoted). They all support our gifted Meta-guru's hidden agenda theory.

Comment: @PetterFriberg So in a thread full of personal attacks and unfounded accusations, what you have a problem with is me stating a few facts that contradict those accusations, without attacking anyone?

Comment: So, people agreeing with his comments, even though the conversation doesn't change afterwards, means the conversation is derailing? I don't follow.  I agree Hans is harsh (I don't see it as rude. Just... curt. Kind of like a grumpy veteran who's seen it all) sometimes (very often is more accurate) when he jumps on a Meta question.... but if all it does is get a couple of upvotes and the conversation carries on.... is it really that bad?

Comment: @Patrice I think a high rep user being rude and getting a pass because of status is bad.

Comment: Okay, the comment's upvoted. Cool? How does that derail your question? How does that get all of the comments off-track? _"everyone jumps on the bandwagon and gets sidetracked from the question I am asking."_ That's what you said happens. I _don't see this happening._ I see people _maybe_ agreeing with his point. There could be millions of other reasons they upvoted that comment too, by the way. They could have randomly upvoted comments, could be they like his user name, could be they like what he said, could be anything. But it _did not_ sidetrack people from the question.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic 100%. But again, I don't see these as particularly rude. If it was, then by all means there should be consequence. Exhibit one is saying "this is a pointless argument, one of the two parties involved has to back off at some point".  How is that rude, really? I personally don't see it as rude at all. I can understand some people disagree... but I don't see it, sorry

Comment: @Increasing, nobody is getting a "rudeness pass". Some people are disagreeing that these comments are rude at all. A tad too harsh? Yes. But within acceptable limits. Can't enforce a uniform level of niceness.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic My friend, rude is very subjective. What you're seeing as rude, I'm seeing as _blunt_ but not rude. I respect that you see it as rude. I also respect that the mods are _not_ seeing it as rude. Ultimately, as they're the only people aside from the commenter who can delete comments, not much we can do to outweigh that. (There is deletion based on number of flags on the comment, but no idea off-hand the rules, or how common that is.)

Comment: @Patrice The way you reworded the is not rude. The difference being the original comment needlessly targets the author and yours does not. It is the difference between saying, "This was not done correctly" and "You must be stupid to have done this". An admittedly extreme example, however both send the same message and one does so politely.

Comment: @yivi, Surely that's why we have flags. If there is a *reasonable chance* a comment can be construed as contravening Be Nice, shouldn't it be removed? In what context would you suggest, **"give up and not come back"** is in line with "Be Nice". In my opinion, in **no context whatsoever**.

Comment: @jpp, in the context of the comment you took that line from. They are not telling you to pack-up and go. They are complaining about a perceived escalation in an alleged conflict with another user.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic Saying 'this is nonsense" doesn't mean "you're an idiot". I can call what you're doing stupid, without saying you are stupid. The first comment calls the fight nonsense, not any of the users involved.

Comment: @jpp But that's not what was said at all.  The sentiment of the comment was very much, "can everyone please calm down and stop escalating so that this situation doesn't require someone to leave just to resolve the problem."  The "someone not coming back" was very much presented as the *undesirable* outcome of that comment, while still making it clear that if the problems continue to escalate that's likely what will end up happening.

Comment: How is "perceived escalation in an alleged conflict" anything to do with my Meta question? **No relation whatsoever. This is what moderators are for, not Meta-gurus.** It's like somebody posting a Meta "why is this question bad?" and somebody responding "because your previous question is bad".

Comment: @Servy *what you have a problem with is me stating a few facts* no I have no problem with this and can't see how this is related to my comment, I was expressing another concern, but never-mind.

Comment: @jpp It's relevant because you were escalating a rollback war.  You made an edit, it was rolled back, you *made it again*, and then asked a meta question about the exact issue that the rollback war related to.  A user suggesting that continuing the rollback war is a bad idea is both a useful statement, and *very relevant to the question*.

Comment: @jpp since you are asking about a specific question, activity in said question can be said to be relevant. **Mind you**, I'm not saying I agree with those comments or that specific position. I'm just saying that I disagree with you saying "they derailed the question", and that those comments are rude, and that anyone who agrees with those comments is a _follower_, which I find extremely condescending.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the connection. My suggestion was "Improve How to Tag Instructions"... **Nothing to do with a specific user**, just a plain suggestion.

Comment: @jpp your question was about "abandoned questions", using a specific question as example, at least insofar "exhibit A".

Comment: @yivi, So how did our gifted Meta-guru get it into this head it had something to do with an internal war? "Good intentions assumed" indeed.

Comment: @jpp I have no idea. That's not the issue here. The issue is that you are saying those comments "derailed the question" and constituted harrassment.

Comment: "good intentions assumed" goes both ways. Assuming everyone who clicks +1 is doing so for the wrong reasons isn't really assuming good intentions either, to be fair.

Comment: @Patrice, I don't have the evidence (mods might), but I can *guarantee* that those who upvoted gifted Meta-guru also downvoted my questions. I know because they happen at the same time, it's not hard to spot the correlation. So do these comments derail the questions: absolutely.

Comment: @jpp Yes, it is indeed possible that the people who upvoted a comment expressing a problem with your question may also have downvoted your question.  But you need to consider that it may well have been because *they agreed with what the comment was saying*, rather than that they cast both votes despite liking your question and not the comment, and instead voting based on the authors of each.

Comment: Not at all what I'm saying here. What I'm saying is that you believe that these votes are for the wrong reason. what if, **legitimately** the users thought Hans point was true, and that this therefore warranted a downvote on the question? And btw, stop with correlating and using that as proof. Meta has a LOT of active users, and when your view count goes up rapidly, it's really easy to correlate some votes together, wrongly.

Comment: @Patrice, While correlation is not causation, when it happens on multiple posts, well... when there's smoke... Surely there's *something* wrong when the only majorly upvoted comments are the ones *unrelated whatsoever* to the Meta-question.

Comment: @jpp come on. How many links and studies do you want to showcase that humans are horrible at drawing conclusions from data like this? In any case, I don't see it as being a problem. What if, reading Hans comment's, I go "hmmm, this guy may be right". Wouldn't the correct move be to upvote his comment, then read the question with that new information in mind, and downvote it because I disagree? Downvotes on meta can mean disagreement, so even IF your correlation is right (I suspect it isn't)... does it really mean anything? I don't believe so.

Comment: @jpp Or, well, coincidence from a _very small_ sample size. You've given us two examples. Just two. If you have more examples, you're using more than we have to prove your point, which leaves us incredibly disadvantaged in the conversation. If you _don't_ have more examples... Maybe go outside, get some fresh air, and come back in an hour to re-read the exchange here?

Comment: @Kendra, Many more examples (**hint**: look at the links *others* have posted here). Thanks for the last patronizing comment, I have enough fresh air.

Comment: My comment was not patronizing, I simply feel that you are getting a bit worked up over this. If you have more examples _(Of the claimed bullying, therefore of comments that pertain to you and are bullying, not comments of this user posting similar things on others' posts)_, as I said, then you're leaving the rest of us at a disadvantage in this discussion. Since you have more examples, the second "If" statement does not execute. But, as you are inclined to assume malice, I will take my leave of this chain of discussion. Good day, and I hope you find a resolution here that suits you.

Comment: @Kendra, I suggest you also get some fresh air. How you can spin a non-negative interpretation on "Is there any chance for this nonsense to stop or does it take having one of you give up and not come back?" is beyond me.

Comment: @jpp Exhibit 2 is a "non-negative interpretation" of Exhibit 1. They both mean the same thing -- "You two should figure out how to coexist peacefully" -- though one is blunter than the other.

Comment: @duplode, I think you misunderstand my point. Exhibit 1 should not be considered a valid response **in any context**. Especially from a hugely respected / high-rep / Meta-guru member of the SO community.

Comment: @jpp can you provide a link to the posts where the comments are please?

Comment: @YvetteColomb, [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365875/should-we-improve-edit-abandoned-questions#comment573247_365875), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365548/improve-how-to-tag-instructions#comment570933_365548).

Comment: Using the 'Be nice' policy as a sword instead of a shield devalues it, just as labeling a disagreement 'bullying' devalues real cyber-bullying:(   If anyone actually believes they are being bullied, they should talk to a lawyer.   Really, it's meta - who cares?  I get beat up on meta often, so what - I've still got beer in the fridge.

Comment: Are you seriously accusing Hans of bullying? He will be proud...

Comment: @jpp: I find the way how you present the first exhibit here very problematic. This is not the full comment and makes it look as if this user left just that text. Full comment is "The OP is not "gone", he visited the site 16 hours ago. Perhaps unimpressed with the answer, him seeing hi-rep SO users that don't like each other messing with his question can't impress him all that much either. Is there any chance for this nonsense to stop or does it take having one of you give up and not come back?". Quoting only the last sentence and then claiming that your question wasn't addressed is  a problem.

Comment: In my opinion, the first part makes it *worse*. Using one fact to push his own agenda.

Comment: @jpp: I disagree about this. Pointing out that you have an edit war on your example question is very important if you want us to discuss questions and policies. That should really have been part of your question because atm it looks as if you came to meta to find others agreeing with you in order to win a fight. I might have written the comment a bit different, but the content is absolutely relevant.

Comment: @jpp Providing relevant facts to support your statements doesn't make your comments worse.  We *want* people to be supporting their statements with facts and evidence.  That you consistently don't is a problem.

Comment: @PetterFriberg although you're free to qualify Hans and Servy how you like and seeing how much support your comment got, let me state that we can't do without them. We need (meta) users that keep a clear mind, know their facts and don't mind voicing their doubts. If their resistance is removed or silenced we end-up with a site that is riddled with out of control bots and voting mobs that operate from chat rooms. You don't have to agree with them but their points of view are always worth considering. Don't make the mistake to use these kind of *incidents* to make them behave like you see fit.

Comment: @rene you are free to support and protect Hans and Servy as well. However, to directly quote one of Servy's meta comments, "As is brought up in comments, yes, not telling people when they do bad things does make them feel better, because it feels bad to be told that you did bad things, but then those people don't realize they were doing something bad, and so are going to make no attempt to improve their problematic behavior, or even realize they're expected to." There are definitely posts from these two that ride the edge of "Be Nice" and "rude or abusive", and maybe they need to hear that

Comment: @rene I'm not sure which comment you are referring to I guess, *tons of knowledge* but *can be intimidating*, your statement *behave like you see fit* is according to me unfair. I'm far from thinking that people will behave like I see fit (not even my kids do, so for sure Hans will not), instead I was directly addressing Servy (since in comment thread). I really hope that telling Servy or Hans that they can be intimidating will not stop their contribution, at best it will make them reason "How can I get my message through, without scaring the user, since I'm me?"

Comment: @PetterFriberg fair enough.

Comment: I don't really understand (2). Regardless of what cause the meta question (the OP cares about SO or just have a fight with someone else), if the overall effect is good it should be applied.

Comment: @jo I'm sorry, but I just can't see what Servy said wrong there. It doesn't come across rude and certainly doesn't *"ride the edge"* of "Be Nice" or "Rude or Abusive".

Comment: @Lankymart I didn't say that the quoted comment was rude.

Comment: @Jo fair enough, reading through I see that now.

Answer (score -26, accepted):

Your flags.

Two mods handled these particular flags and I was one of them.

This second one you flagged with a "rude or abusive" flag and I handled this.

[image]

When I reviewed it I considered a few things.
- Is it rude or abusive?
- It's on meta and meta lends itself for expression of opinions. As long as no one is being actively insulted, people are allowed to have opinion and express their opinions.
- He's not being abusive. He's stating what he sees as a fact, it's blunt, but telling people to be tolerant of one another is basically good advice.
As to the truth of the claim between you and another user, I didn't want to remove it, rather allow the community to make up their own mind.

The first comment you linked I deleted just now.

This one you used a custom flag.

[image]

Saying that one of you may have to leave the site is not nice and we don't  tell people to get lost, in any form.

If you have a problem with another user that you cannot resolve, create a custom mod flag describing the problem or contact the community team using the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) link.  Flag, ignore, move on.

Comment: But that comment *isn't* telling them to get lost.  It's telling them to stop an edit war because the only way the edit war is going to end is if someone just leaves it alone.

Comment: Hans is not saying someone has to leave, he is saying *one of you give up and not come back* which I read as: *we will lose one valuable contributor*. Hans want it to stop, for the better of both of them. Instead you honor the flag of a user which to me seem to have their own agenda. Despite all comments on the question, I think Hans is valuable with his often opposing views and having him silenced in this way is not good. The comment needs to be undeleted.

Comment: I handled each flag under it's own merit. Whatever agendas people have - I'm staying out of that. That is why I left the first comment - you can all discuss it, but just be nice. If there's roll back wars and disputes on the main site, flag it, and we will deal with it there.

Comment: I don't see what merits deletion of the second comment. That comment is not expressing what you state as the reason to delete it. So unless there are other pressing reasons you haven't shared yet, the comment is deleted in error by a moderator.

Comment: @rene I'm not revealing the details of the custom flag, I thought it was reasonable and deleted it. I've discussed it with another mod and we both thought it should go.

Comment: Fair enough,. At least we still have the pictures to enjoy ;)

Comment: @YvetteColomb If the comment was deleted for reasons you can't share, then at least say that, rather than saying it was deleted for telling people to leave the site, when *the comment was doing the exact opposite* and trying to *prevent* people from leaving the site.

Comment: Though the comment itself could lend a hand to baiting so I can at least see why it would be removed.

Comment: i mean, to be fair, neither of those comments are asking for or providing clarification of the question, so them being deleted isn't really outside of the realm of possibility regardless of whether or not either was rude.

Comment: Two observations: (1) Other posts / comments have it the other way round, the first is more offensive, (2) Both these comments are highly upvoted by Meta users. *At a minimum*, there is a **disconnect** with moderation and what is considered reasonable. We *all* need educating.

Comment: @jpp if you count yourself in **all** we gained at least something.

Comment: I do, indeed, in good faith. I hope you would also agree with my comment. It's a little disappointing another comment on one of these posts by a different Meta-guru had to be removed for being rude.

Comment: it is unfortunate that we keep having to be petty :)

Comment: Flagging rude comments is petty? I didn't get that last comment.

Comment: No, that by itself isn't @jpp but publicly announcing your success with it to show off  how  "*good*" you are is. And stop calling me a meta-guru.

Comment: @rene, If you think my comment is rude, the correct action is to flag.

Comment: I sure will, I don't need encouragement for that @jpp but thanks.

Answer (score 21):

> *How can I ask a question without it being manipulated into a perceived war with another user?*

Short answer: You don't.

Longer answer:

If someone wants to see a rat where you're presenting a ladybug, you're unlikely to convince them otherwise. Don't bother trying. So long as they don't take the question off-topic, you might as well ignore their comment about "wars" with other users.

Now, if it *does* derail the comments, okay, you have a problem. But that has two possible fixes:

1. You can edit your question to clarify that it has *nothing* to do
   with whatever the comments are carrying on about, then flag the
   offending off-topic comments and explain to a mod that they are not
   relevant to the question. They are not needed for the post to
   continue, and they do not critique or request clarification.
2. You can also, with or without doing the previous (though I find it
   works better with) ask in the comments for the off-topic comments to
   end, and point out that it has nothing to do with your question.
   This is almost always easier if your question has been clarified,
   but sometimes the comments are so wildly off that you really
   shouldn't have to clarify. If the comments continue, you can usually
   flag for a mod to clean up the off-topic comments or remind folks
   that the comments are for critique/clarification, not for off-topic
   discussion. (This could even happen without a flag, if a mod wanders
   by and notices.)

As for *persistent bullying,* if someone is actually bullying you, definitely flag and explain to a mod. Link to examples, as best you can. But keep in mind that someone showing up on multiple posts you've made in a community with a small number of active users doesn't mean they are bullying you, even if you disagree with their comments or they read too much into your question. Remember that just because they're wrong/off-topic does not mean they are bullying you, it means they are wrong/off-topic.

Nothing you've linked to or shown us so far has come across as more than a misinterpretation, off-topic comments, or just *a clarification or critique of the post.* They are blunt, sure, but not everyone (indeed, it seems to me like a majority of the Meta community fits this, from my experience) would see this as rude. Some will, sure, but some will also see me saying "I'm a cat person" as rude.

Just for completeness, this is the full extent of each comment. Yes, this context *does* matter:

Comment 1:

> The OP is not "gone", he visited the site 16 hours ago. Perhaps unimpressed with the answer, him seeing hi-rep SO users that don't like each other messing with his question can't impress him all that much either. Is there any chance for this nonsense to stop or does it take having one of you give up and not come back?

This was indeed an attempt to critique/clarify your question. It was blunt, sure. Perhaps a tad harsh. Rude? Not what I would call rude, no. Bullying? Most certainly not. I see nothing wrong with this comment. Could it have been worded differently so that it did not come across so bluntly or harshly? Most certainly. Most comments on the sites (all of them, not just Meta) can be. That does not make them *rude,* however.

They do not attack you. They do not act like you are stupid, they do not curse or insult anyone. They are blunt. The "nonsense" comment is, to my reading and the reading of at least a couple others in the comments above, in reference to the blooming edit war on the post you linked to in that question. The user has definitely seen pointless edit wars, and indeed, some of them do go on until someone gives up and does not return to the post. Others go until a mod steps in. Could've been worded better, but I still do not see it as rude.

Comment 2:

> A tag that is favorited by 75,500 users and 95,000 questions does not have an exposure problem. There is something going on between you and another hi-rep [python] contributor, having that spill over into meta like this is not productive. Learn to live with each other, be tolerant.

Yeah, I see no relevance between this comment and the question it was posted on. Perhaps they posted it to the wrong question, perhaps they misread the question... However, I still do not see it as rude *(Being wrong, misreading things, and such are not rude and the comment still does not attack you in any way, shape, or form. They simply misunderstood. If misunderstanding was rude, I'd be offended every minute of every day by the people I work with.)* and it most certainly did not derail your question. This was the only comment about this topic on the question.

Please remember that rudeness is *highly subjective.* As I said earlier in this answer, someone could *very easily* find "I'm a cat person" rude, and what am I supposed to do about that? Refrain from being a cat person? In the end, if the mods disagree that it is rude, the only thing you can do is raise a question on Meta about how you don't understand how it isn't rude, and people will either agree and you'll get an apology, or people will explain that they also don't find it as rude (as has happened here) and you'll have to decide how you want to take things from there.

In the end, if you feel like the "Be Nice" policy and its enforcement disagree? That's a completely different Meta post, and you're going to want more than two examples for sure if you want to prove it. A lot more than two.

Comment: Kendra: How many should find a comment offensive for a mod to consider it contravenes "Be Nice"? Are the above comments *insufficient*, or just because *you* find it relevant it's fine?

Comment: upvote just for (H)answering this minefield.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I only deserve that upvote if said answer adaquetely hit the target of addressing the question and not the comment minefield, without blowing up too many mines in the process. :)

Comment: @jpp I must say that I dislike some that the comment present in question was not the whole actual comment, please next time present complete comment. I see how you feel it's a non nice comment, but presenting 1/2 comment is also not fair.

Comment: Concerning the second comment: the first sentence is probably meant to rebut the second paragraph of the question. `<speculation>` The rest of it is likely a reference to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365538/5764553) posted the same day. As you can see from the first comment over there, Hans saw two users having a disagreement. When jpp asked a separate question on almost the same subject, Hans probably thought that jpp was trying to stir up support separately. `</speculation>`

Comment: Also, to clarify what happened here, comment 1 was flagged 32 minutes before this question was asked, wasn't even seen by a moderator until after this question was asked, and was just deleted 15 minutes ago. The flag was marked as helpful, as was another "rude or offensive" comment flag on the same post. Meta flags aren't always handled as quickly as ones on SO, because we have to remember to check over here separately.

Comment: The truth is I only found out about the earlier Meta later!  And I have no problem with his Meta either. My "enemy" upvoted my Meta fyi.

Comment: @Jpp you keep on acting as if you know who upvotes what... between the people who upvote hans comments and also downvote the questions, or who upvotes your meta posts... you have knowledge everyone else lacks.....

Answer (score 13):

I think the problem is that your meta questions leave out that there was a disagreement on the questions you link to. For example, in your latest question you say:

> My idea is to add some version information (which is likely to be
>   important to any answer) and possibly offer a bounty to encourage a
>   good response.

This makes it sound like you wanted feedback before you did anything. However, when one goes to the question they discover that you've already made the change and had in fact applied the edit multiple times because someone else rolled your changes back.

It happens that occasionally there will be a meta question from a user complaining about someone else's behavior but it's soon discovered that they left out the part where they initially insulted the other person or that this is someone they've fought with before. By leaving out that this argument happened, this *looks* like the same sort of thing. You may have left it out because it wasn't relevant but it ends up looking like you left it out because you want to win the fight.

To avoid this in the future acknowledge that a disagreement happened up front. Something like, "I'm asking because I thought X was correct but another user pretty strongly it should be Y. I want to know what the community thinks in the general case so I can do the correct thing moving forward."

If you are on good terms with the other user then you could also ask them to participate in the meta discussion right when you open it.

Comment: The said user has told me he does not wish to participate on Meta. I am not surprised.

Comment: Exactly this. And the question didn't get derailed at all. The first 4 comments are about what you describe here. The other 6 comments and the answer directly address your question.

Comment: +1 for good intent. *To avoid this in the future acknowledge that a disagreement happened up front.* As our friends on Meta would say, "Do you [really](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365548/improve-how-to-tag-instructions#comment570937_365548) [think](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364058/how-should-i-deal-with-claims-that-my-answer-is-plagiarism-of-another#comment561848_364058) that makes any difference? What world you living on?"